# Where should I set the AWS access key excatly

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

What I want is:

- Access S3 data by Hive like `create table ... location 's3n://bucket/path'`
- Use `hadoop distcp from to` or `hadoop fs -cp from to`
- Use our proxy server when I access S3

My questions are:

1. Where should I set AWS access key exactly?
2. How can I set proxy ?

My search so far:

- For question 1, the answer from Google are, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, hive-site.xml and yarn-site.xml, I mean... NOT ALL OF THOSE right ?
- For question 2, the answer is hadoop/conf/jets3t.properties. But there isn't such a file, should I put a new file in?

We are using Hadoop 2.2.x, Hive 1.x. And We don't want to put access key on url...yet.

Thanks.

---

Edit 2017/05/26

- Only core-site not working
- core-site, hdfs-site and hive-site can
- The effect of jets3t.properties is unknown(Not working, maybe because of other reasons)

Comment: Would you be using AWS SDK based tools? If so, you can put the credentials in `~/.aws/`

Comment: Are you using Amazon EMR? If not, is your Hadoop cluster running on Amazon EC2 or on-premises?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein We are not using EMR, just data putting on S3 only

Comment: Is your Hadoop cluster running on EC2 or on-premises?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein On-premises